# 1 based indexing double digit number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to decrypt this string a12b20 to aaaa..12timesbbbbbbb...20times but my code can only execute char by char if i have to execute with a double digit number it won't return anything
Please give me advise to modify this code
Edit : Also if in the string contain character like cd3 means it will repeat cdcdcd

```
def kThCharaterOfDecryptedString(s, k):
    compress_str = ""
    str1 = ""
    lastdigit = ""
    i = 0
    while i<len(s):
        str1 += s[i]
        if str1.isdigit() == True:
            for char in range(int(str1)):
                compress_str += lastdigit
            lastdigit = ""
        else:
            str1 = ""
            compress_str += s[i]
            if len(lastdigit) == True:
                lastdigit += s[i] 
            else:
                lastdigit = s[i]
        i += 1
    if k in range(len(compress_str)):
        return compress_str[(k-1) % len(compress_str)]
    else:
        return -1
s = 'a12b20'
k = 8 
print(kThCharaterOfDecryptedString(s, k))
```

coding problem was to execute to kth character in the decrypted string
I executed it with the single digit in mind so it failed multiple testcases
I thought of using another function which will take length or at least find multiple digit but it gave me a runtime error

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use regular expressions like Andrej suggests, you can fix your own character-by-character parsing logic by keeping track of the chunks being parsed, and adding the correct number of letters to the result once a number chunk ends, i.e. you encounter another letter, or the string ends

```
def decrypt(s):
    number_chunk = []
    letter_chunk = []
    result = []
    
    for c in s:
        if c.isdigit(): # If c is a digit, append it to number_chunk
            number_chunk.append(c)
        else:
            
            if number_chunk: # If c is not a digit, and number_chunk is not empty, 
                text = "".join(letter_chunk)
                count = int("".join(number_chunk)) # Convert the list of characters into a number
                for _ in range(count): # Append the last chunk to the result list, count times
                    result.append(text)

                # Reset number_chunk and letter_chunk to an empty list for the next chunk
                number_chunk = [] 
                letter_chunk = []
            
            # Append the new character to the result list
            letter_chunk.append(c)
    
    # Finished processing the string. Handle the last number chunk if needed
    if number_chunk:
        text = "".join(letter_chunk)
        count = int("".join(number_chunk))
        for _ in range(count):
            result.append(text)
            
            
    return "".join(result) # Join all characters in the result list and return


r = decrypt("a2b5c10d20")
print(r) # aabbbbbccccccccccdddddddddddddddddddd

r = decrypt("pq10")
print(r) # pqpqpqpqpqpqpqpqpqpq
```

---

From here, `kThCharaterOfDecryptedString` needs to just return the `k-1`th character of `decrypt(s)`, i.e. `decrypt(s)[k-1]` (because you mention `k` is a 1-based index)

---

If you don't want to calculate the entire decrypted string (possibly because the decrypted string would be long and you don't have enough memory) you could just keep track of the current character and the length of the decrypted string so far, and return it if the desired index is reached:

```
def kThCharaterOfDecryptedString(s, k):
    current_char = ''
    current_char_index = 0
    number_chunk = []
    letter_chunk = []
    desired_index = k-1
    for c in s:
        if c.isdigit():
            number_chunk.append(c)
        else:
            if number_chunk:
                count = int("".join(number_chunk))
                next_chunk_index = current_char_index + (count * len(letter_chunk))
                
                if next_chunk_index > desired_index:
                    letter_index = (desired_index - current_char_index) % len(letter_chunk)
                    return letter_chunk[letter_index]
                
                current_char_index = next_chunk_index
                number_chunk = []
                letter_chunk = []

            letter_chunk.append(c)
            
    if number_chunk:
        count = int("".join(number_chunk))
        next_chunk_index = current_char_index + (count * len(letter_chunk))
        
        if next_chunk_index > desired_index:
            letter_index = (desired_index - current_char_index) % len(letter_chunk)
            return letter_chunk[letter_index]
```

---

Both approaches now work with your given example:

```
k = 9000
s = "dajidas988ksajlkdn908"

r = decrypt(s)
print(r[k-1]) # j
print(kThCharaterOfDecryptedString(s, k)) # j
```

Comment: current char may not be the kth character in some cases For Example input : dajidas988ksajlkdn908 kth character: 9000 desired output: j but your code output 'n'

Comment: @AniRoll I assumed the number only applies to the last letter before it, which is why you get that output. Both approaches will need to be changed to handle multiple characters being repeated. You can try to extend the same logic for `number_chunk` to a `letter_chunk`, I'll edit my answer in a few hours

Comment: @AniRoll I edited my answer to add `letter_chunk` logic to both functions, take a look now

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` module for parsing the string, e.g.:

```py
import re


def decrypt(s):
    out = []
    for ch, count in re.findall(r"([a-z])(\d+)", s):
        out.extend(ch for _ in range(int(count)))
    return "".join(out)


s = "a12b20"
print(decrypt(s))
```

Prints:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```